# How automatically add steps to test case in MS Test Manager from associated Coded UI Test

Tags: visual-studio-2010, coded-ui-tests, microsoft-test-manager

I started work with Coded UI and Microsoft Test Manager (MTM). 
Consider, I created test-case in MTM with some steps.
I can running it manually and record my actions for each step. Then I can associate CodedUI test with test-case in MTM. VisualStudio automatically generates recorded steps to c# methods with the same names.

```
     this.UIMap.OpenSAV();
     this.UIMap.AcceptTerms();
     this.UIMap.LoginAsInternal();
     this.UIMap.DeclineUpdates();
     this.UIMap.SelectEffectivity();
```

I need inverse problem. I want create CodedUI test with some methods, associate it with test case so that in test-case in MTM happend steps with names of methods.

Link to image of steps in MTM. [Steps in MTM](http://www.screencast.com/t/Ntz7bD0fE1Nc)

Comment: I think this is not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't a supported scenario. You could use the exploratory testing tool to quickly run through the test and generate your test steps for you though, then do the association with your coded ui test.